# Drag&Drop and Duration change in anychart Gantt chart

Tags: javascript, anychart

I cannot figure out what to listen after, when using drag&drop or duration cahnge in an anychart Gantt chart

I get data from a json call and have the following code

```
chart = anychart.ganttResource();
chart.data(anychart.data.tree(data, 'asTable'));
var dataGrid = chart.dataGrid();
chart.editing(true);
```

I'm locking at https://docs.anychart.com/Gantt_Chart/Live_Edit_UI_and_API in the documentation, but it doesnot say what to listen after. 
I have tried to do

```
var tree = anychart.data.tree(data, 'asTable');
tree.listen("treeItemUpdate", function(e) {
              alert("test");  
            });
```

But the alert does not show.
EDIT:
I do get the alert, seems I had a typo in my code.

The drag&drop and duration change is working fine, but I need to store the changes in the DB, but as I wrote I cannot see what trickers it.

EDIT2:

I have changed the alert to show the information mentioned in the documentation, so I have

```
tree.listen("treeItemUpdate", function(e) {
                console.log(e);
              alert("test " + e.type + " " + e.item + " " + e.path + " " + e.field + " " + e.value + " " );  
            });
```

The alert gives something like this

```
test treeitemupdate [object Object] periods,2,start periods 1512574122684 
test treeitemupdate [object Object] periods,2,end periods 1512583122684
```

While the consolelog shows

```
Object { type: "treeitemupdate", target: {…}, c: {…}, f: false, l: false, yA: true, item: {…}, path: […], field: "periods", value: 1512405943770 }
```

opening the item gives me this, but I cannot see how to work with this data

```
item: {…}
P: Object { b: {…}, P: null, f: […], … } 
b: Object { yb: false, yj: undefined, ai: {…}, … }
c: Object { nc: true, depth: 1, index: 2, … }
f: Array []
g: Object { id: "270", rowHeight: 15, periods: […] }
h: Object {  }
__proto__: Object { get: g.get(), set: g.set(), Ve: g.Ve(), … }
```

My chart looks like this
[Gantt Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9YbA.jpg)

My json is like this

```
[{"id":"0",
"collapsed":false,
"rowHeight":15,
"userLevel":"0"
},{
"id":"4",
"collapsed":false,
"rowHeight":15,
"name":"(1 - jnb) Bjerre, Janine Nedergaard ",
"userLevel":"3"
},{
"id":"270",
"parent":"4",
"rowHeight":15,
"periods":[{
    "id":"270_2",
    "stoke":"none",
    "start":"1512370800000",
    "end":"1512464400000",
    "fill":"#DCE4EF",
    "personID":4,
    "id_task":"270"
    },{
    "id":"474_3",
    "stoke":"none",
    "start":"1512543600000",
    "end":"1512547200000",
    "fill":"#DCE4EF",
    "personID":4,
    "id_task":"474"
    },{
    "id":"140_6",
    "stoke":"none",
    "start":"1512548100000",
    "end":"1512743400000",
    "fill":"#DCE4EF",
    "personID":4,"id_task":"140"}]
},{
"id":"488",
"parent":"4",
"rowHeight":15,
"periods":[{"
    id":"488_4",
    "stoke":"none",
    "start":"1512543600000",
    "end":"1512547200000",
    "fill":"#DCE4EF",
    "personID":4,
    "id_task":"488"
    },{
    "id":"485_7",
    "stoke":"none",
    "start":"1512554400000",
    "end":"1512561600000",
    "fill":"#DCE4EF",
    "personID":4,
    "id_task":"485"
    },{
    "id":"247_8",
    "stoke":"none",
    "start":"1512564960000",
    "end":"1512568560000",
    "fill":"#FFFFFF",
    "personID":4,
    "id_task":"247"}]
},{
"id":"372",
"parent":"4",
"rowHeight":15,
"periods":[{
    "id":"372_5",
    "stoke":"none",
    "start":"1512547200000",
    "end":"1512556200000",
    "fill":"#DCE4EF",
    "personID":4,
    "id_task":"372"
    },{
    "id":"222_9",
    "stoke":"none",
    "start":"1512565200000",
    "end":"1512568800000",
    "fill":"#DCE4EF",
    "personID":4,
    "id_task":"222"}]
},{
"id":"313",
"parent":"4",
"rowHeight":15,
"periods":[{
    "id":"313_10",
    "stoke":"none",
    "start":"1512566400000",
    "end":"1512570000000",
    "fill":"#FFFFFF",
    "personID":4,
    "id_task":"313"}]
},{
"id":"26",
"collapsed":false,
"rowHeight":15,
"name":"(aal) Aalb\u00e6k, Arne ",
"userLevel":"3"
 },{
"id":"423",
"parent":"26",
"rowHeight":15,
"periods":[{
    "id":"423_12",
    "stoke":"none",
    "start":"1512370800000",
    "end":"1512401400000",
    "fill":"#DCE4EF",
    "personID":26,
    "id_task":"423"}]
},{
"id":"6",
"collapsed":false,
"rowHeight":15,
"name":"(tc) Clausen, Tom ",
"userLevel":"1"
},{
"id":"436",
"parent":"6",
"rowHeight":15,
"periods":[{
    "id":"436_14",
    "stoke":"none",
    "start":"1512367200000",
    "end":"1512738000000",
    "fill":"#DCE4EF",
    "personID":6,
    "id_task":"436"}],
},{
"id":"508",
"parent":"6",
"rowHeight":15,
"periods":[{
    "id":"508_15",
    "stoke":"none",
    "start":"1512370800000",
    "end":"1512471600000",
    "fill":"#DCE4EF",
    "personID":6,
    "id_task":"508"}]
}]
```

And I need to identify the id_task I have in my periods.

So I rephrase my question and ask for guidance to how I use the data I get in my listen(), especially how I identify the object I working on and get the data in that object

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there! Try the following listener with your Gantt Chart and your JSON data:

```
            tree.listen("treeItemUpdate", function(e) {
            var periodInfo = e.item.get('periods')[e.path[1]];
            console.log('treeItemUpdate - ' + 'row ID: ' + e.item.get('id') + ', id_task: ' + periodInfo.id_task +
            ', personID: ' + periodInfo.personID + ', ' + e.path[2] + ': ' + e.value);

//next line will show you the unformatted period info which is modified 
           // console.log(periodInfo);
        });
```

Now you will get info about a period you are modifying.

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot, but have let me to another question, is there a way to either say that "Changing duration" can only be on end time, or to have the Chart editable, but not allowing Changing "duration". Or how do I in the "treeItemUpdate" see if it's a "Changing duration" or a "DragDrop" event?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no method to not allow a certain type of events. But with some code tricks, there's an opportunity to identify "Changing duration" or a "DragDrop" event. I prepared an example for you here - https://jsfiddle.net/1hbfbszc/
Launch that fiddle, open browser console and try to move periods and change its duration. All required information you will find in comments.

Comment: I simplified the extra code in my previous example, new example is here - https://jsfiddle.net/fp3j016g/